# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE when composite key

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert new rows in MySQL table only if the combination of 3 of the existing columns (`ID`, `Type`, `Year`) is not unique. In case these 3 columns match I want to update the field 'Val' only.

This is the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Abs` (
 `ID` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
 `Type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Year` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `val` decimal(4,1) DEFAULT NULL, ....
```

That's why I created composite index and use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY, trying to save IF THEN blocks.

In my table there are not any rows with `Type` = 0, but following seems to insert nothing.

```
INSERT INTO `Abs` (`ID`, `Type`, `Year`, `Val`) VALUES (141, 0, 2013, 5) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Val` = 5
```

This is my composite index:
    ALTER TABLE `Abs`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(
     `ID`,
     `Type`,
     `Year`);

What would be the best approach in that case. I assume that this is a pretty common case in RDB world, but couldn't find easy solution.

Comment: Have you looked at `REPLACE INTO`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Yes, REPLACE INTO `Abs` (`ID`, `Type`, `Year`, `val`) VALUES (141, 0, 2013, 0) seem to work, provided I made UNIQUE first 3 columns: ALTER TABLE `Abs` ADD UNIQUE (`ID` ,`Type` ,`Year`); Anyway INSERT/UPDATE is more logical for me in that case.

Comment: Your table, index & insert query should works just fine... They do here.

Comment: Yes, they do, seems case closed. I found additional indexes in my table, so deleting them resolved the issue. What to say - phpMyAdmin shows which columns have indexes, but indexes are some how hidden. So composite index of first 3 columns works fine. Thank you.